# Validate if amount is changed - Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to validate amount changing

for example: 
`Balance = 1 and user adds 1`

how  to validate that the balance will be 2?

```
<div class="balance__amount">
    1 GEL
</div>
```

after adding +1

```
<div class="balance__amount">
    2 GEL
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use driver.findElement and compare the two innerHTMLs. You might need another function for the calculating the result of balance + user input.

Try starting with this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className('balance__amount')).getAttribute("innerHTML").then(
//do something
);
```